# Split a string with delimiters in the value

Tags: python, string, dictionary, split

I am trying to parse the response from a REST call. The response header comes back in the format of a dictionary. The ultimate goal is to decode all the properties (value of x-ms-properties) to strings.

The response is in the format.

```
{'Last-Modified': 'Mon, 06 May 2019 09:32:13 GMT', 'ETag': '"0x8D6D205B880F304"', 'Server': 'abc', 'x-ms-properties': 'anotherprop=dGVzdA==,source=YWJj', 'x-ms-namespace-enabled': 'true', 'x-ms-request-id': '45839301-401f-0003-1202-04d929000000', 'x-ms-version': '2018-03-28', 'Date': 'Mon, 06 May 2019 11:54:29 GMT'}
```

I would like to parse the value of the key x-ms-properties. If you see, the value is in the form of key- value pairs. And the value is base64 encoded.

I can decode the value dGVzdA== statically using the code.

```
import base64
b1="dGVzdA=="
# Decoding the Base64 bytes
d = base64.b64decode(b1)
# Decoding the bytes to string
s2 = d.decode("UTF-8")
print(s2)
```

But how do I parse the response and then do this generically?

I have read the forum posts and tried something like

```
originalresp={'Last-Modified': 'Mon, 06 May 2019 09:32:13 GMT', 'ETag': '"0x8D6D205B880F304"', 'Server': 'abc', 'x-ms-properties': 'anotherprop=dGVzdA==,source=YWJj', 'x-ms-namespace-enabled': 'true', 'x-ms-request-id': '45839301-401f-0003-1202-04d929000000', 'x-ms-version': '2018-03-28', 'Date': 'Mon, 06 May 2019 11:54:29 GMT'}

properties=originalresp["x-ms-properties"]

dict(item.split("=") for item in properties.split(","))
```

But of course it fails, as my properties has "==" in the value, because of the base64 encoding.

How to get the value for this key and then proceed on to my decoding?

Comment: If the question is just "How do I split only on the first instance of '=' instead of all of them?", provide an argument to split's `maxsplit` parameter: `"foo=bar==baz".split("=", 1)` gives `['foo', 'bar==baz']`

Comment: You are only missing the `sep` argument in your split on equals, that's it, rest the code is perfect @SaugarMukherjee!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing missing in the code is you need to tell `split('=')` to only consider the first equals, which you can do by `item.split("=",1)`

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

> str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)
>    Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string. If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done (thus, the list will have at most maxsplit+1 elements).

So making this change, we see

```
originalresp={'Last-Modified': 'Mon, 06 May 2019 09:32:13 GMT', 'ETag': '"0x8D6D205B880F304"', 'Server': 'abc', 'x-ms-properties': 'anotherprop=dGVzdA==,source=YWJj', 'x-ms-namespace-enabled': 'true', 'x-ms-request-id': '45839301-401f-0003-1202-04d929000000', 'x-ms-version': '2018-03-28', 'Date': 'Mon, 06 May 2019 11:54:29 GMT'}

properties=originalresp["x-ms-properties"]

#Changed the split on equals here with maxsplit=1
dct = dict(item.split("=",1) for item in properties.split(","))
print(dct)
```

The output will be

```
{'anotherprop': 'dGVzdA==', 'source': 'YWJj'}
```

Now your original code will work as expected :)

```
import base64
# Decoding the Base64 bytes
d = base64.b64decode(dct['anotherprop'])
# Decoding the bytes to string
s2 = d.decode("UTF-8")
print(s2)
```

The output will be `test`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ast` module

**Ex:**

```
import ast

originalresp="""{'Last-Modified': 'Mon, 06 May 2019 09:32:13 GMT', 'ETag': '"0x8D6D205B880F304"', 'Server': 'abc', 'x-ms-properties': 'anotherprop=dGVzdA==,source=YWJj', 'x-ms-namespace-enabled': 'true', 'x-ms-request-id': '45839301-401f-0003-1202-04d929000000', 'x-ms-version': '2018-03-28', 'Date': 'Mon, 06 May 2019 11:54:29 GMT'}"""
originalresp = ast.literal_eval(originalresp)
print(originalresp["x-ms-properties"])
```

**Output:**

```
anotherprop=dGVzdA==,source=YWJj
```